# How to have the correct representation of words in C+python+UART?

Tags: python, c, uart

In a serial communication, I need to send that ciphertext from python to UART which is able to read it by using C.

At first, In the python side use this technique:

```
ciphertext=(b'\x24\x70\xb4\xc5\x5a\xd8\xcd\xb7\x80\x6a\x7b\x00\x30\x69\xc4\xe0\xd8')
ser.write(ciphertext)
```

In the C side, I put the received ciphertext in a buffer. I test If the first byte 24, the Start of the packet:

```
if (buffer_RX[0]=='\x24')
{
   for (i=1;i<=17;i++) //sizeof(buffer_RX)==17
   {
       printf("%x \n",buffer_RX[i]);
   }
}
else {
   printf("It is not a packet!");
}
```

The result that I have is:

```
70
b4
c5
5a

d8
cd
b7
80

6a
7b
0
30

69
c4
e0
d8
```

So I have two questions, 
- The fist is why `\x00` is displayed by that way, I mean just one zero 0?
- The second is how could I have this same representation:

```
const unsigned int ciphertext[4] = {0x70b4c55a, 0xd8cdb780, 0x6a7b0030,0x69c4e0d8};
```

If I suppose that is concatenation between bytes, I mean that is maybe:

```
   unsigned int plaintext[1];
   plaintext[1]= buffer_RX[3]|buffer_RX[4]|buffer_RX[5];
```

But I am not sure, I think that I have a syntax error.

This representation will help me to continue next steps. But I don't know how  could I have it please.

Comment: `printf("%02x\n",buffer_RX[i]);` will answer your first question.

Comment: @wildplasser, it corrects me the 0, but it send another d8  the last  byte  seperated. d and 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a 4 bytes long data from your 1 byte chunks.

```
const unsigned int ciphertext[4] = {0x70b4c55a, 0xd8cdb780, 0x6a7b0030,0x69c4e0d8};
```

It is not enough to OR the bytes, you have to shift them into the right position.

What you are currently doing, (note that you are over indexing `plaintext[1]` this should be `plaintext[0]`):

```
unsigned int plaintext[1];
plaintext[1]= buffer_RX[3]|buffer_RX[4]|buffer_RX[5];
```

has this result in the memory, assuming `int` is 32 bit, 4 byte long:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3. byte | 2. byte | 1. byte |                   0. byte                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0x00   |   0x00  |   0x00  |   buffer_RX[3] | buffer_RX[4] | buffer_RX[5]   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

so you have to shift the appropriate bytes to the right position with the left-shift operator first `<<`, and OR the bytes after that.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char buffer_RX[4];

    buffer_RX[0] = 0x70;
    buffer_RX[1] = 0xb4;
    buffer_RX[2] = 0xc5;
    buffer_RX[3] = 0x5a;

    unsigned int plaintext[1];

    plaintext[0] = (buffer_RX[0]<<24) | (buffer_RX[1]<<16) | (buffer_RX[2]<<8) | buffer_RX[3];

    printf("plaintext: %08x\n", plaintext[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

[image]

In memory:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|     3. byte     |     2. byte    |     1. byte    |     0. byte    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  buffer_RX[0]   |  buffer_RX[1]  |  buffer_RX[2]  |   buffer_RX[3] |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can see that `buffer_RX[0]` has been shifted by **24** which is 3 byte so it skips the first three cell, jumps to the last one.

`buffer_RX[1]` by **16** which is 2 byte, so it skips to first two, `buffer_RX[2]` by **8** which is 1 byte, so it skips the first. And `buffer_RX[3]` was not shifted because it goes to the first place.

---

Regarding the `0x00`, it is zero represented on 8 bits. If your print it, that will be simply **0**. If you print `0x0000` it will be **0** as well. It just how `printf` prints **0** by default, it does not prints zeros unnecessarly. If you have `0x70` in a 32 bit variable then it is actually `0x00000070` but `printf` will print `0x70`, because unnecessary zeros are chopped off, unless you tell otherwise. That is where `%02x` comes in. In the `%02x` the `02` tells `printf` that you want to display 2 bytes no matter what so it will print two zeros in case of `0x00`

```
printf("%02x \n",buffer_RX[i]);
```

If you want to print the whole 32 bit (4 byte) of `0x00000070` the following line will do that:

```
printf("%08x \n",buffer_RX[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.