# How to make concatenation between 4 bytes?

Tags: c

I have 4 bytes:

```
buffer_RX[3]= \x70;
buffer_RX[4]= \xb4;
buffer_RX[5]= \xc5;
buffer_RX[6]= \x5a;
```

I want to concatenate them in order to have such representation 0x70b4c55a:

I already did this `plaintext[1]= (rx_buffer[3]<<8)|rx_buffer[4];`
This is the result that I have: `70b4`

```
plaintext[1]= (rx_buffer[3]<<8)|(rx_buffer[4]<<8)|(rx_buffer[5]<<8)|rx_buffer[6]
```

It doesn't work. 
Please I need help.

Comment: Change each "8" to respectively "24", "16" and "8".

Comment: Shift them more. You have ORRed three values into the same place. And `plaintext[1]` needs to be a 32-bit unsigned value.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "have such representation". The code you are trying to write produces the *value* 0x70b4c55a; how that's represented depends on your platform.

Comment: Yes I need to have that result 0x70b4c55a.

Comment: If you know the value (`0x70b4c55a`), can't you just assign it to `plaintext[1]`?

Comment: I am struggling to understand the close vote for "too broad" - this is on the contrary a very narrow question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have the correct representation of words in C+python+UART?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831263/how-to-have-the-correct-representation-of-words-in-cpythonuart)

Comment: @BenceKaulics, I am the same person, I posted the first question , when I think about cancatenation I posted another question, Thank you very much, I already like you answer

Comment: @nani92 I know, I know :) . But basicly this question is [the same as](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it :

```
plaintext[1] = (buffer_RX[3] << 24) |
               (buffer_RX[4] << 16) |
               (buffer_RX[5] << 8) | buffer_RX[6];
```

Comment: @nani92 : Yes it works but do you now understand why?  Learning that is perhaps more important than being given the answer with no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that each byte is 8 bits, and that 4 bytes is therefore 32 bits.  The first example works because you are using only 16 bits and two bytes, to work with 32 bits and four bytes you must shift each byte by 24, 16, 8 and 0 bits respectively in order to place then into the correct position.

```
plaintext[1]= (rx_buffer[3] << 24 ) | 
              (rx_buffer[4] << 16) |
              (rx_buffer[5] << 8) |
               rx_buffer[6] ;
```